# How to protect static content on IIS7 in Classic Mode?

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

I know how to protect my static (HTML) pages in IIS6, and how to do it using the IIS7 Integrated Pipeline, but how can I protect my HTML pages from unauthorised access in IIS7 when running in Classic Mode?

It's an ASP.NET site using forms authentication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIS Classic Mode is the same as IIS6, except you can't use the IIS manager interface to do it; you have to edit web.config directly. See [this guide](http://www.ifinity.com.au/Blog/Technical_Blog/EntryId/66/How-To-301-Redirect-htm-or-html-pages-to-DotNetNuke-aspx-pages) for details.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET forms authentication has nothing to do with resources that aren't handled by ASP.NET, like HTML files.  Two options:

1) Tell ASP.NET to handle the static file types you are concerned with (HTML, etc) 
2) Disable anonymous access for your site

But now you've got me curious... how does this change with IIS7 Integrated Pipeline vs Classic mode?

Comment: I've now found this link: http://www.ifinity.com.au/Blog/Technical_Blog/EntryId/66/How-To-301-Redirect-htm-or-html-pages-to-DotNetNuke-aspx-pages which shows the different ways of doing it. Since there seems to be little difference in IIS7 Classic vs IIS6, it looks like I've just made a mistake somewhere.